# FormulaArray inserted from C# API only displays the first item in array until array formula is edited and recalculated

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-formula, office-interop

**Background:** I'm using the C# .NET COM API to retrieve data from a source using an API, then loading that data into a spreadsheet using the .NET Excel interface. I'm also using the Excel interface to create a "View Sheet", which I have conditional formatting, data validation, index match formulas etc.
I'm using .NET 8.0 and Excel version 16.0

My problem is with array formulas. In the LOADSHEET (where I dump the raw data from the API), I have text separated by a comma delimiter.

Cell **[B2]** has Data Validation as follows:

```
Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)newSheet.Cells[2, 2];
range.Validation.Delete();
range.Validation.Add(
    XlDVType.xlValidateList,
    XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertWarning,
    Formula1: "=INDIRECT(\"LOADSHEET!$A$2:\"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(LOADSHEET!$A:$A)+1,1))"
);
range.Validation.ErrorTitle = "Value Error";
range.Validation.ErrorMessage = "Please select a value from dropdown list.";
range.Validation.ShowError = true;
range.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
range.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
```

Then the formula in D6 is:

```
newSheet.Cells[6, 4].FormulaArray = "=(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(INDIRECT(\"LOADSHEET!$D$2:\"&
    ADDRESS(COUNTA(LOADSHEET!$A:$A)+1,1)), MATCH(B2, INDIRECT(\"LOADSHEET!$A$2:\"&
    ADDRESS(COUNTA(LOADSHEET!$A:$A)+1,1))), 4), \",\")))";
```

In excel that puts

```
{=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(INDIRECT("LOADSHEET!$D$2:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(LOADSHEET!$A:$A)+1,1)), MATCH(B2, INDIRECT("LOADSHEET!$A$2:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(LOADSHEET!$A:$A)+1,1))), 4), ","))}
```

When the spreadsheet is saved and closed, there is no pre-selected value in B2. There is no formatting done to E6 or D6 besides setting them to left horizontal align, and setting the column width.

At first I tried adding event handlers using Sheet.Change += Change_Handler

```
Sheet.Change += Change_Handler;

private static void Change_Handler(Excel.Range target)
{
    if (target.Address == "$B$2")
        target.Worksheet.Calculate();
}
```

This didn't change anything.

I tried using various different ways of setting the value, such as:

```
newSheet.Range["D6"].Value2 = [Formula];
newSheet.Cells[6, 4] = [Formula];
```

Both of these didn't work, except instead of the formula being wrapped in curly brackets {}, there was an '@' symbol before the TRANSPOSE formula.

Source Data:

| Name | Client | Client-ID | Values1 | Data1 | Data2 | Client Type | Instance Type | Values2 | Last Updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Internal - Inactive - 2/27/2024 | Internal | 10 | RANDOM_VALUE,OTHER_RANDOM_VALUE | 0 | 0 | Inactive | Inactive | ANOTHER_RANDOM_VALUE,FINAL_RANDOM_VALUE | 27/02/2024 |

Current output:

| Values1 | Values2 |
| --- | --- |
| RANDOM_VALUE | ANOTHER_RANDOM_VALUE |

Expected output:

| Values1 | Values2 |
| --- | --- |
| RANDOM_VALUE | ANOTHER_RANDOM_VALUE |
| OTHER_RANDOM_VALUE | FINAL_RANDOM_VALUE |

**It's worth noting that the formula does work if you edit the formula (dont change it) and press enter while in the Excel Desktop Client**

Comment: Try to use `Formula2` instead: `newSheet.Cells[6, 4].Formula2 = `